# AngularJS No output No errors

Tags: angularjs, filter, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat, http-request

After many hours I thought my code is running, but I get no output in my table...
Can't find the error...
the `console.log($scope.articles)` has the full array of articles.

jscode:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.tables", []).controller("articlesCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter",

    function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
        var init;
        $http.get('SOMEURL').success(function (data) {
            $scope.articles = data;
            console.log($scope.articles);
        }).
            error(function (data) {
                // log error
            })
            , $scope.searchKeywords = "", $scope.filteredArticles = [], $scope.row = "", $scope.select = function (page) {
            if (!$scope.currentPageArticles || !$scope.currentPageArticles.length) { return; }
            var end, start;
            return start = (page - 1) * $scope.numPerPage, end = start + $scope.numPerPage, $scope.currentPageArticles = $scope.filteredArticles.slice(start, end)
        }, $scope.onFilterChange = function () {
            return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1, $scope.row = ""
        }, $scope.onNumPerPageChange = function () {
            return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1
        }, $scope.onOrderChange = function () {
            return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1
        }, $scope.search = function () {
            return $scope.filteredArticles = $filter("filter")($scope.articles, $scope.searchKeywords), $scope.onFilterChange()
        }, $scope.order = function (rowName) {
            return $scope.row !== rowName ? ($scope.row = rowName, $scope.filteredArticles = $filter("orderBy")($scope.articles, rowName), $scope.onOrderChange()) : void 0
        }, $scope.numPerPageOpt = [3, 5, 10, 20], $scope.numPerPage = $scope.numPerPageOpt[2], $scope.currentPage = 1, $scope.currentPageArticles = [], (init = function () {
            return $scope.search(), $scope.select($scope.currentPage)
        })()

    }
])}.call(this));
```

HTML-Code:

```
   <section class="panel panel-default table-dynamic">
    <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Artikel</strong></div>

    <div class="table-filters">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <form>
                    <input type="text"
                           placeholder="Search..."
                           class="form-control"
                           data-ng-model="searchKeywords"
                           data-ng-keyup="search()">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="th">
                    ID
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-up"
                          data-ng-click=" order('idArticles') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == 'idArticles'}"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down"
                          data-ng-click=" order('-idArticles') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == '-idArticles'}"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="th">
                    Artikelgruppe
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-up"
                          data-ng-click=" order('artGroupName') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == 'artGroupName'}"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down"
                          data-ng-click=" order('-artGroupName') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == '-artGroupName'}"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="th">
                    Artikelname
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-up"
                          data-ng-click=" order('artName') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == 'artName'}"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down"
                          data-ng-click=" order('-artName') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == '-artName'}"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="th">
                    Preis
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-up"
                          data-ng-click=" order('artPrice') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == 'artPrice'}"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down"
                          data-ng-click=" order('-artPrice') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == '-artPrice'}"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="th">
                    EGIS-Artikelnummer
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-up"
                          data-ng-click=" order('egisArtId') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == 'egisArtId'}"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down"
                          data-ng-click=" order('-egisArtId') "
                          data-ng-class="{active: row == '-egisArtId'}"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="th">
                    Sichtbarkeit
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="articles in currentPageArticles">
            <td>{{articles.idArticles}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.artGroupName}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.artName}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.artPrice}}€</td>
            <td>{{articles.egisArtId}}</td>
            <td class="articles_active text-center">{{articles.active}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <footer class="table-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 page-num-info">
                <span>
                    Zeige
                    <select data-ng-model="numPerPage"
                            data-ng-options="num for num in numPerPageOpt"
                            data-ng-change="onNumPerPageChange()">
                    </select>
                    Einträge pro Seite
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right pagination-container">
                <pagination class="pagination-sm"
                            ng-model="currentPage"
                            total-items="filteredArticles.length"
                            max-size="4"
                            ng-change="select(currentPage)"
                            items-per-page="numPerPage"
                            rotate="false"
                            previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;"
                            boundary-links="true">
                </pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</section>
```

Please help.

Comment: your ng repeat has currentPageArticles instead of articles

Comment: but with articles the filters doesn't work...

Comment: the code is huge, can you come up with a fiddle/plunkr to demonstrate your issue

Comment: [plunkr-link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lMJdNPQRCa0pttY6WYMT?p=preview)  i don't get it work in plunkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you had was that you updating the filteredArticles when searching however you not applying the same in the table. Had a fix on it and here is the [Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wn1crsyzZECqc1iur5NT?p=preview)

Code Changed:

HTML:

```
    <tr data-ng-repeat="articles in filteredArticles">
            <td>{{articles.idArticles}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.artGroupName}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.artName}}</td>
            <td>{{articles.artPrice}}€</td>
            <td>{{articles.egisArtId}}</td>
            <td class="articles_active text-center">{{articles.active}}</td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
  $http.get('data.json').success(function (data) {
            $scope.articles = data;
            $scope.filteredArticles = data;
            console.log($scope.articles);
  })
```

Comment: nice, thx. but the nums per page doesn't work. And I think the sort by id doesn't work because it's parsed to string.

Comment: I don't get the pagination work... It's out of a template and I think it's not the right way to do it with http.get...